# which one will be given priority in Tomcat 6: index.html or index.jsp?

Tags: web-applications, tomcat6

Our web app contains both index.html and index.jsp, and we use Apache Tomcat 6. When a request having the path till the context (for eg.,http://localhost:8080/mysite) comes to the tomcat which one will be served ?

Is this index.html or index.jsp ?

Is it configurable ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`index.html` will be given preference, but you can change this under `welcome-file-list` in `web.xml`.

```
<welcome-file-list>
   <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
   <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
   <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

In the event of a partial request, the above configuration will try `index.jsp`, then `index.html`, and then `index.htm`.