# index.html ignored or default servlet got priority over index.jsp and index.html? Why?

Tags: java, servlets

**web.xml**

```
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>TestFilter1</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>



<servlet>
    <servlet-name>ser1</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.gaurav.test.Hello</servlet-class>    
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ser1</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>    
</servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

**index.html**

```
<body>
HelLoSTHTML
</body>
```

**index.jsp**

```
<body>
HelLoSTJSP
</body>
```

**Hello.java**,*implementing **javax.servlet.Servlet***

### ***service method***

```
PrintWriter out=paramServletResponse.getWriter();
out.println("HelloTextStart");
out.println(config);
out.println("HelloTextEnd");
out.close();
```

deployed on **jboss-5.1.0GA**

## now cases

1. **requesting

   > /TestFilter1/

   **
   ***showing***

   > "HelloTextStart
   >   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperFacade@1a878065 HelloTextEnd "

   ***but not showing***

   > "HelLoSTHTML"
2. **requesting

   > /TestFilter1/index.html

   ** then also
   ***showing***

   > "HelloTextStart
   >   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperFacade@1a878065 HelloTextEnd "

   ***but not showing***

   > "HelLoSTHTML"
3. **requesting

   > /TestFilter1/index.jsp

   **
   ***showing***

   > "HelLoSTJSP"

So what is the order of processing/prioritizing this request?
(html,jsp.Servlet ser1)

Comment: could you paste your complete web.xml file please ?

Comment: i have pasted complete web.xml
thanks and help me

Comment: AFAIK it process from top to bottom if it dont find the file then goes for the next one

Answer (score 0):

Your application works as configured. You tell to your webapp : 
When you see request coming send them to the servlet class `com.gaurav.test.Hello`

Conf:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>ser1</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.gaurav.test.Hello</servlet-class>    
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ser1</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>    
</servlet-mapping>
```

So this servlet is responding to your request.
I think want you need is to configure the servlet `javax.servlet.Servlet`

I hope this will help

Comment: how to configure the servlet javax.servlet.Servlet?

Comment: Replace  <servlet-class>com.gaurav.test.Hello</servlet-class>   by  <servlet-class>javax.servlet.Servlet</servlet-class>

Comment: javax.servlet.Servlet is an interface this can not instantiate.

Answer (score 0):

we can configure the URL-patterns in 3 ways

```
1) Absolute/Exact Matching (Ex: <url-pattern>/test1</url-pattern>)
2) Extension Matching      (Ex: <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>)
3) Directory Matching      (Ex: <url-pattern>/abc/*</url-pattern>)

<url-pattern>/</url-pattern> means Every Request go to Hello.java
```

First it will check Exact matching then Extension there after Directory Matching.

Above code for every request is going to Hello.java.

go through this link you will get clarity [which one will be given priority in Tomcat 6: index.html or index.jsp?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2049772/1990992)

Comment: when i am trying /TestFilter1/index.html the it should go to that index.html file?

Comment: and welcome file list have index.html.
/TestFilter1/ should search first from welcome file list?
and if it do so, it'll find index.html file